# Count number of killed processes

Tags: sorting

we have total n processes in a computer and a new process denoted by x is waiting in a queue.
    we also have given the memory of all the n processes.
    now the task is to find the minimum number of processes killed to be replaced by a new process.
    suppose n=5
    (memory size for new process)x=9
    and memory occupied all 5 processes=2 1 3 4 5.
    now if we remove 4 and 5 then the minimum count is 2 (4+5=9).
    i have tried this in o(n^2) but i want optimize solution.
    please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if we are allowed to manipulate the process list that was initially given to us, you can simply sort the list of processes in descending order of magnitude. Then, the problem boils down to just iterating over the list and summing the memory allocation of each process you encounter. When you exceed x (i.e. the allocation required for the new process) you just return the current index + 1, which is the number of processes you have encountered (and killed) so far.

Below is a sample Python code implementing it.

```
def solve(processes, x):
    processes.sort(reverse=True)
    sum_of_freed_memory = 0
    for i in range(len(processes)):
        sum_of_freed_memory += processes[i]
        if sum_of_freed_memory >= x:
            return (i+1)
    return -1 # to not crash if/when total memory is smaller than x
```

You may observe this code at work [here](http://ideone.com/aYtDE7), producing the output you desire.

Note that even if we could not manipulate the original list given as input, if we are allowed to use O(n) space in our solution, we may copy the initial list and use the same algorithm on that copy. In terms of code, replacing the first line of the function solve() with the line given below would do it.

```
    processes = sorted(processes, reverse=True)
```

The approach this code takes is greedy. At each step, it reasons in the following manner: **if** I have to kill one more process, then among the ones still running, **let's kill the one using the largest memory, so that the chances of allocating sufficient memory are the highest possible**. In other words, if there is a way of allocating enough space by killing one more process, killing the one using largest memory will do it, whereas killing some other process may be insufficient. Although it is not that formal a proof, I believe this reasoning explains why the algorithm works.

The complexity of sorting is **O(NlogN)** and the traversal is **O(N)**. Thus, the overall complexity of the algorithm would be **O(NlogN)**.

Comment: I solve this problem using sorting in c++, but We are not allowed to use any S.T.L. so that's why i have to write the program for sorting the array which is given to us  and it will increasing the complexity of my code.

Comment: Whether you write the sorting function yourself or use a given library is irrelevant if both implementations are correct. The only possible difference would then be a constant factor, which is not considered to be an increase in complexity in terms of big-o notation, which you seem to consider, given your usage of it in your question.